# Short circuit in induction motor

Tags: short-circuit, induction-motor

[image]

I have one question. Refer Image attached by me. There is Main Motor M1 connected by star delta starter and M2 is fan motor whose connection is taken from Delta contactor. I have question here IF there is short circuit happen in fan motor/ In its connection will that short circuit current will flow through M1 Motor stator winding?IF No then Why?

Answer (score 1):

In general, short circuit current flows by the most direct route from the source to the short circuit. The the voltage across the short is practically zero. However there is some voltage drop in the resistance of the conductors at the short and between the short and the source, so the source voltage is distributed all through the distribution system. As a result, the voltage supplied to other loads is reduced, tending the reduce the current in other loads. However energy stored in the inductance of motors and other inductive loads can be returned to the distribution system in the form of current supplied to the short circuit. In some cases, other motors can act as generators for a brief time, transferring energy stored in the rotating inertia of driven equipment to the distribution system in the form of current to the short circuit.